# PHP not recognizing MySQL installation

Tags: php, mysql

Fellas,

I have wasted about 4 hours of my life on this and now I am coming to you. I realize this has been asked before, but I have extensively read similar questions and still cannot figure out what I am doing wrong. I installed PHP 5.2.17 and Apache 2.2 using this source: http://www.thesitewizard.com/php/install-mysql-windows-vista.shtml

The installations worked just great and I have been using them to work on my computer. I recently decided I wanted to try to add MySQL as well. I used the same source (which is the link above) to install MySQL. I installed the latest version of MySQL (5.5) and everything seems to have gone smoothly in regards to installing it on my computer.

In my PHP.ini file, the following are set and not commented out:

```
extension_dir = "c:\php\ext"
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

The PHP folder is in the correct place, and I have looked and seen that the .dll files do exist in the "ext" directory. I have both restarted both Apache and my computer since making all of the above changes.

phpMyAdmin gives me this error: "The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration." and the function phpinfo(), when called in a test.php page, is not recognizing the MySQL extensions (to verify it is working with PHP) as my source tutorial site said it would.

In addition, I added this ";c:\php" to my system variables under Path as instructed by my tutorial site. Again, I restarted the computer after all of this was done. Have restarted Apache many times. MySQL is allowed in the correct port. Any thoughts?

Thanks for your time, I highly appreciate it.

EDIT: just in case it makes any difference, I installed in MySQL without a password because it was saying my root password was wrong or something, so I uninstalled it and then reinstalled it without the password and the installation went all the waythrough.

Comment: Do you see the correct `extension_dir` in your phpinfo?

Comment: are you sue that php.ini is the one being loaded? `php -v` and/or `phpinfo()` will both tell you which ones are being loaded.

Comment: Yup, under both local and master value.

Comment: Yeah it says C:\PHP\php.ini under loaded configuration file.

Comment: comment the mysqli extension and try to work with regular mysql do discard mysql problems

Comment: Does `phpinfo()` show that the mysqli extension is loaded?

Comment: commented that back out (that is how I originally had it), restarted apache, still no instances of mysql showing up on phpinfo() page.

Comment: crush, I've been finding "mysql" or "sql" to try to verify if it was loaded on phpinfo(). does it not say it directly?

Comment: `API Extensions mysql,mysqli,pdo_mysql` is what you should see on `phpinfo()`

Comment: Yeah, not there. Frustrating.

Comment: Then I'd say that Marc B is correct, and you are not modifying the correct php.ini file.