# PHP MySQL, PHP not recognizing that MySQL module is installed

Tags: php, mysql, windows, iis

So I've installed PHP v5.2.9 in order to run WordPress. When I go visit the domain, I get the following error:

"your php installation appears to be missing the mysql extension which is required by wordpress"

In my php.ini I have the following lines uncommented:

```
extension=php_mysql.dll
extension=php_mysqli.dll
```

The extension_dir which I've double check that it actually exists is:

```
C:\PHP\ext
```

My php.ini is loaded from:

```
C:\WINDOWS\php.ini
```

When I run `<? phpinfo() ?>` in my test.php file everything is just as you see it above with the only exception being, MySQL or MySQLi aren't listed. Under "Additional Modules" there is nothing loaded.

[PHP not recognizing MySQL installation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14489039/php-not-recognizing-mysql-installation)

I've read this post where the comments pretty much say the wrong php.ini file is being loaded/modified. This doesn't appear to be the case. I've editing the php.ini file located in the C:\WINDOWS\ directory. When I change the extension_dir and restart the server. the changes take affect. The only thing that doesn't seem to work is adding modules.

Just an FYI I'm running:

PHP 5.2.9

Windows Server 2003

IIS v6.0

And MySQL is in fact installed and works.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the problem with the help of this guy.

https://wordpress.org/support/topic/your-php-installation-appears-to-be-missing-the-mysql-#post-253130

I just needed to copy the libmysql.dll file into the system32 folder.